# How to convert an input to string

Tags: python

```
while n == 1:
    w = inputs.append(input('Enter the product code: ')) 
    with open('items.txt') as f: 
        found = False
        for line in f:
            if w in line:
```

So this is the part of the code with the issue. After the last line a bunch of stuff happens which is irrelevant to the question. When i run it, i get the error:
    if w in line:
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not NoneType

I know it's because i need to convert w to a string somehow but i don't know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Append returns none. Save the input then append.

Comment: what do you mean by save the append?

Comment: Save *the input*, then append the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) already returns a string, so there is no need to convert it.

You have this:

```
w = inputs.append(input('Enter the product code: '))
```

You should be doing this in two steps, since you are assigning `w` to the return value of `append()`, rather than the return value of `input()` in this case. `append()` will always return `None` regardless of the user input, so `w` in your program will be assigned to `None`. Instead, try:

```
w = input('Enter the product code: ')
inputs.append(w)
```

Comment: Yeah someone answered this before but i didn't understand it, thanks to both of you

Comment: @Anya, does it make sense now?

Comment: Yeah it does, i understand where i went wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you, i'm really new to stack overflow (only made an account yesterday).